How to delay API calls in Node/Javascript?
I have spent countless of hours on this but I can't seem to get it right. I have to make 150 api calls at once, because the API I'm using does not have a batch API. The limit on the API is 150 calls per 10 seconds.
Essentially, I'm trying to upload files via the API which takes the file from and sends it via a formData.
I managed to get it to work, but I keep getting 429 errors, API limit reached, because for some reason my delay is not working.
Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?
Below is my code:
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
import FormData from 'form-data';


const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

export const upload = async () => {
    
    fs.readdir(FOLDER_PATH, async (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reading folder:', err);
            return;
        }

        let filesCount = files.length;
        console.log(filesCount)
        let min = 0;
        let max = min + 150;

        while(max <= filesCount){
            let endpoints = files.slice(min, max);

            let start_time = new Date().getTime();

            try {
                const responses = await Promise.allSettled(endpoints.map(async (singleFile) => {
                    const filePath = `./uploads/Files/${singleFile}`;
                
                    // Create a readable stream
                    let data = new FormData();
                    data.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filePath));
                
                    try {
                        // Make the API call using async/await
                        const response = await axios.post(API_URL, data, {
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
                                ...data.getHeaders()
                            },
                            maxContentLength: Infinity,
                            maxBodyLength: Infinity                        
                        });
                        return response.data;
                    } catch (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                }));         

                const results = responses.map((result) => {
                    if (result.status === "fulfilled") {
                        return result.value;
                    } else {
                        console.error(`Failed to fetch data from one of the endpoints: ${result.reason}`);
                        return result.reason; 
                    }
                }).filter(result => result !== null); 

                //Write to CSV File here
        
                await delay(10000);
                let end_time = new Date().getTime();
    
                let timeTaken = end_time - start_time;

                console.log(timeTaken)
                

                if(max == filesCount) {
                    console.log("Done")
                    break;
                }
                min = max;
                max = max + 150;
    
                if(max > filesCount){
                    max = filesCount;
                }
                console.log("Files Updated");
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }           
        }   
    });
}

I'm using Node an Express

for some reason my delay is not working. ... you never use it?

@JaromandaX Thanks, I accidentally removed it while removing unnecessary code before the post. I added it back to where I put it

Are you sure the delay is not working? Is it possible the API enforces the rate limit differently or maybe even wrong?

@JaromandaX That's the issue, I'm not really sure where it should go. I tried a few things but I am just not being able to wrap my head around it

@VLAZ it doesn't work, unfortunately I'm doing something wrong here but I can't see what

by the way, if you use try/catch and all catch does is throw error, there's no need for try/catch :p

Sorry, I misread your code to be honest - I thought the delay was inside the async map, it isn't :p

FYI readdir comes in a promise variety so you don't need the callback function ~ https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options

Have you tried a longer delay (11 seconds) - perhaps the API timing is not very accurate - can you confirm from your console that you at least appear to be within the API rate limit?

delay works correctly: https://jsbin.com/hikagedoyi/1/edit?js,console - what are you basing your observation that it doesn't?

I'm going to guess the API is using a "fixed window" algorithm (I'm more of a "token bucket" man myself) so you could easily be exceeding the limit if say the usage window starts every 10s by the clock

@VLAZ on my local it seems to work, but on the server it doesn't. I just don't get it

@JaromandaX Tried 15-20 seconds as well. I tried to put the delay before everything. On local, it works, on server it doesn't/

so, the code runs differently on different servers ... that makes it less possible to debug for us

@JaromandaX I am not sure though, because i'm literally just runnin gnpm run start:dev both sides with the same node version. I will try to debug it more, but it seems quite odd. I'm so confused

console.log with times will be useful for you to check timings

Promise.allSettled  One issue with Promise.all is that it will execute everything in one go, IOW: Your making 150 concurrent requests at the exact same time, the 429 might be a concurrent API limit, rather than the requests per 10 second limit.  A better approach might be to use an async map with a concurrency setting.   eg.  Maybe still do your 150 requets per 10 seconds, with maximum of 10 concurrent connections.   Doing 150 request at the same time can cause thrashing anyway, you might find even dropping to 3 concurrent connection is faster than 10..

@Phil  I think it might actually have something to do with the Secondary rate limit which sits at 15 per second.  Although I can technically do 150 per 10 second, there seems to be an error which is the Secondly rate limit reached, and when I look at the API docs, it shows 150/10sec (OR 15/second). Is that what could potentially cause this problem?

@VLAZ I think you might want to check the comment above. You might have been onto something. Would appreciate your input
